# Store objects that maintain their own internal immutable state, inside an array of stores

Tags: javascript, redux

Before I begin, please let me say that I have no intentions of implementing the following inside a React/Redux application. This question is hypothetical only.

The following code uses Redux to generate an array of Redux store objects inside an array. Each store has the ability to maintain it's own internal state object as this is what Redux does.

My question, albeit a simple one, is, is an array of store objects, which are capable of maintaining their own internal state, immutability?

Could this array be passed throughout an application and the states within the stores updated by dispatching actions to the appropriate store via the stores array index without mutating? i.e. `stores[0].dispatch({ type: 'VALUE1' })`

If the array needed to ever have a store removed, I'd imagine you could use `array.filter` to return a new array of store objects? Thank you

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const fake = function fakeReducerFunction(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'VALUE1':
      // Return new state object
      return
    case 'VALUE2':
      // Return new state object
      return
    default:
      return
  }
}

const numStores = 10
const create = function createArrayOfStores(counter = 0, array = []) {
  const store = createStore(fake)
  if (counter === numStores) return array
  return create(counter + 1, [...array, store])
}

const stores = create()
stores[0].dispatch({ type: 'VALUE1' })
```

Comment: It's really hard to answer this question without understanding what you're actually wanting to accomplish, and why you would even try something like this in the first place.

Comment: I'm asking this question because I have built an API that uses polyglot persistence (Neo4j, MongoDB, Postgresql, and Redis) and I used the concept of a Redux store to create an internal state object for each request that track a request as it traverses the different databases and allows me to have complete control and do things like rollback changes if one of the databases fails. I want to break what is currently a single store and a giant reducer into separate stores.